# Do global variables cause a load on the server in php?

Tags: php, function, include

I was wondering if global variables like `$_SERVER`.. cause any load on the server if used multiple times? My code right now is basic but for good coding practice, should I be setting these to their own variable and using it that way or just use the global more than once?

My problem that leads me to ask this question is that I have 2 functions the rely on `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` for a path it needs and it has to use that twice when running one page so I was curious if it would help performance to set it to a a variable and use it that way. If that is better, how would I do that? When I define it outside of the function I am unable to use it within the function.

Thanks,

Comment: It doesn't cause any extra load, it's already a variable ;) If you want to use variables defined outside of a given function or scope, you should use `global $var;`

Answer (score 0):

you can use $_SERVER as much as you want, setting it to a variable is again waste of little memory,
$_SERVER is available as as an assoc array

Answer (score 0):

No. God no. Even if it did, it's just a variable access. You're not computing pi, you're just accessing a variable. If there was any difference it'd be so minimal you'd have a hard time proving it. Worry about such things when you have a case for it, like that your site is actually slow.

Answer (score 0):

The `$_SERVER` variable is automatically set by the web server that is hosting the PHP, and I believe that it is set before the execution of your script. Referencing the `$_SERVER` variable is not going to pass anything off to the server since the value has already been set. Unless you want to put `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in another variable for clarity (although I think that using the server variable itself is clear enough), there is no need.

Also, you don't need to be too concerned about things like this as far as performance goes. Your real bottlenecks are going to be found in the database layer and any computationally intensive tasks.